# Better way to access individual Rails ActiveRecord error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to access the type attribute of an ActiveRecord::Error object. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to redirect a user to a different page depending on the type of validation that failed (an attribute can fail validation in several ways, so the attribute itself is insufficient).

The only way I've found that I can do this is:

`obj.errors.instance_variable_get(:@errors)["attr"][0].type`

which is just plain nasty. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your best bet is to extend `ActiveRecord::Errors`.

```
class ActiveRecord::Errors
  def error_type(attr)
    @errors[attr] && @errors[attr].first.type
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also found an undocumented public method called each_error, but I like your approach better.