# Default ActiveRecord/ActiveModel ::Errors are anonymous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel, custom-errors

Default ActiveModel::Errors are great, but i am solving problem, that the messages are anonymous. For example there is message `should look like an email address.` that belongs to `email` field, but what i want is to know that this error message is `format` type. And the other message `doesn't match confirmation` is `confirmation` type.

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000001054abef0 @base=#<User ... >, 
    @messages={
        :password=>["doesn't match confirmation"], 
        :email=>["should look like an email address."]}>
```

Is there any gem for better errors, or do any of you have idea of monkey patch?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671098/better-way-to-access-individual-rails-activerecord-error

Answer (score 0):

In rails validations, you can add custom messages to be passed up the exception food chain, generated from the model.

[ActiveRecord validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Comment: I know that :) But it is not exactly what I want. I want to recognize in Error object which message belongs to which type of validation and use it for example with javascripts validations.